# CURL timeout on remote machine after enabling UFW on server

Tags: curl, ufw

I have two machines. On the primary machine, I have UFW enabled.
From the client machine, if I issue the folloing command, I am getting a timeout

```
curl 192.168.15.212:8080/colibri/stats
```

There is a valid response if I change UFW rule to allow 8080 from ALL,

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

But i wish to keep the path accessible only to private specific IPs. Appreciate the help.

Following is the current UFW ruleset on the primary server.

```
sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # SSH
[ 2] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # WEB
[ 3] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # WEB SSL
[ 4] 53                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # DNS
[ 5] 123/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # NTP TimeSync
[ 6] 123/tcp                    DENY IN     Anywhere                   # Trojan 123
[ 7] 4443                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Jitsi2
[ 8] 10000:20000/udp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Jitsi3
[ 9] 4444                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Jitsi2
[10] 4440:4500/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Jitsi2
[11] 4440:4500/udp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # Jitsi2
[12] 5250:5300/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # prosody
[13] 8443/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # clibri
[14] 8000:9000/udp              ALLOW IN    192.168.13.47              # Colibri
[15] 8080                       ALLOW IN    192.168.13.0/24           
[16] 8080/udp                   ALLOW IN    192.168.13.0/24            # Colibri
[17] 22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # SSH
[18] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # WEB
[19] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # WEB SSL
[20] 53 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # DNS
[21] 123/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # NTP TimeSync
[22] 123/tcp (v6)               DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)              # Trojan 123
[23] 4443 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Jitsi2
[24] 10000:20000/udp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Jitsi3
[25] 4444 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Jitsi2
[26] 4440:4500/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Jitsi2
[27] 4440:4500/udp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # Jitsi2
[28] 5250:5300/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # prosody
[29] 8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # clibri
[30] 8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thank You. Seen that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow a single IP to any port with UFW. 
In your master machine run:

```
sudo ufw allow from <client-IP> to any port 8080
```

Check if your client machine has open port 8080

Comment: Also note that you have 8080 still open to ipv6

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions. I have added a rules on master  and restarted UFW --  [14] 8080                       ALLOW IN    192.168.13.47     . I have also disabled UFW on client. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to trouble shoot it by enabling UFW logging and monitoring the logs

```
 May  4 14:46:46 meet kernel: [364297.922390] 
[UFW BLOCK] IN=enoXX OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
SRC=192.168.250.2 
DST=192.168.XX.XXX 
LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=44 ID=26775 
PROTO=TCP SPT=19662 DPT=23 
WINDOW=30150 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

The key is the SRC IP which is not 192.168.13.47 but 192.168.250.2. This  might be down to the switching or to the fact that 13.47 is a VM.